# Why is formData not a constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, tinymce

I am working with a TinyMCE editor and I've followed their demo and another tutorial to the 'T'.  My goal is to use the image uploader to enable the user to upload images to the server. 
 However, when I use the image uploader to select an image, the error "formData is not a constructor" pops up.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR4jd.jpg)

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var json;
    
          if (xhr.status != 200) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
          }
          json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    
          if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
          }
          success(json.location);
        };
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), fileName(blobInfo));
        xhr.send(formData);
      }
```

I followed the instructions here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#imageuploaderoptions

The other tutorial I utilized (which is just about the same thing) is here:
https://www.codexworld.com/tinymce-upload-image-to-server-using-php/comment-page-1/#comment-61677

Comment: `formData` or `FormData`? `new FormData();` works fine.

Comment: The error uses "formData" even if I change my var name to something else. I verified that I typed FormData(); I'm not sure why the error uses the lowercase f.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Google Chrome and get the listed error.  I just tried Internet Explorer and it says "fileName" is undefined.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for me in this TinyMCE Fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/fzgaab  Do you see errors there?  I have tested in Chrome (latest).

Comment: The code still doesn't work for me.  It's now saying fileName is not defined

Comment: Did you solve this, i have the same `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: FormData is not a constructor` because `FormData`  is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the variable name 'formData' to initialize to a constructor 'FormData', the variable name overrides the constructor definition. So it should be:

```
var FormRequest= new FormData();
```

But your variable CANNOT be named FormData. I just ran into this in a Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

If you've change the name and still getting the same error, perhaps it's caching the old page.  If using chrome or fitefox you should be able to add a breakpoint in that function and step to the exact line with the error.

Everything looks right with the code